# Differences of location services

Tags: android, google-maps, location-client

I newbie in location and trying make service to show my current location and another one location saved previously. And what the difference of using `LocationListener` vs `LocationClient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LocationListener connects to the LocationManager and retrieves your location. This worked and works fine.

The LocationClient is a new way to implement this while some of the rest gets deprecated. It features more functions.

Both methods actually works.

Answer (score 1):

**Location Manager** was introduced in Android SDK and can be used as a feature of android.

**Location Client** is something that's part of Google Play SDK and is introduced in the recent Google IO 2013.

You can understand that since **LocationClient** is the latest, it is more efficient in getting the location with minimal energy(battery drain) with greater accuracy.

Reasons to use **LOCATIONCLIENT** because:

- The location update behavior is very abnormal and wont work as you expect. i.e. The location updates get stuck when switching networks. (It keeps giving you some old location)
- The location client wont work on modified android versions of the android OS, as it requires Google play services.

`Location Client` might be good on the battery of the phone but it won't be good with giving you timely accurate location updates.

I recommend good old Location Manager as I don't find location client reliable at all.

**Note :** There is no point of saving battery if you are not even getting your current location in a location based application.